# how to add/override a new nginx configuration file?

Tags: nginx, rhel8

I have a somedomain.com.conf file under /etc/nginx/sites-available in linux (RHEL). if i want to host a web app/site, do i just edit the same file or create a new configuration file for nginx? I edited this file and it works, but trying to find the right way to do this. is the convention , create a new config file for each site/app, you host?

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mysite.com;

    charset utf-8;
    root /var/www/mysite-folder;
    index index.html index.htm;

    location / {
            root /var/www/mysite-folder;
            try_files $uri /index.html;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought the RHEL-based systems doesn't make use of that `sites-enabled`/`sites-available` mechanism at all (in opposite to Debian-based distros). Of course, the most common approach is to use a separate files for each hosted domain name (maybe including the subdomains). All those files are being included from the top level configuration file `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` at the `http` context level; the Debian packages usually have

```
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

lines in that file while RHEL packages usually have only the single

```
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
```

line. As you can see files in the `sites-enabled` directory may be named any way while files in the `conf.d` directory should have the `.conf` extension to be included (and you can rename it so something like `<donain>.off` to temporary exclude from nginx configuration). What directory to use for your vhost configuration is up to you (I personally prefer to use `/etc/nginx/conf.d/` since it is a more universal way). There is a big [Difference in sites-available vs sites-enabled vs conf.d directories](https://serverfault.com/questions/527630/difference-in-sites-available-vs-sites-enabled-vs-conf-d-directories-nginx) thread on this subject on ServerFault (the whole question is more suited for ServerFault rather that StackOverflow; please next time ask this kind of question there).